# How to rescale IQ data after changing data set in the frequency domain

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to filter out a signal from my IQ data. First I view my signal in the time domain and select the data points for the time I'm interested in, then I go to the frequency domain and select the frequency I'm interested in. Once I select my data in the frequency domain, when plotting with the Sampling Frequency (Fs) I collected the data with, the bandwidth of my plotted signal is no longer correct. Is there some kind of scaling I need to do before going back to the time domain?

After changing bandwidth and time of my signal, how do I compensate?

```
left_sample = (11.06/1000)*Fs;
right_sample = (13.06/1000)*Fs;

signal_time = IQ_complex(left_sample:right_sample);

Y_shifted = fftshift(fft(signal_time));

left_freq = 35747; %This is an index, not f in Hz
right_freq = 53183;

signal_freq = Y_shifted(left_freq:right_freq);
```

I am expecting the signal I clipped out to be its original frequency time but it gets stretched to my original bandwidth.

I tried calculating a new sampling frequency, which makes my plot look correct, but I think the data is not scaled properly:

```
Fs_f = length(signal_freq)/.002;
```